# Mutable live-data give multiple response give old response from api and after give new response

Tags: android, retrofit, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

**Mutable live-data give multiple response old response from api and after give new response **

mutable live-data give multiple response

here is my code

Repository

```
suspend fun forgotPassword(email:String,sig: String,salt: String):Response<ForgotDataClass>{
    return RetrofitInstance.api.forgotPassword(email,sig,salt)
}
```

View model

```
class ForgotPasswordViewModel(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

var myPassword: MutableLiveData<Response<ForgotDataClass>> = MutableLiveData()
fun forgotPassword(email: String, sig: String, salt: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = repository.forgotPassword(email, sig, salt)
        myPassword.value = response
    }
}
```

}

api interface

```
@POST("forgot_password.php")
 suspend fun forgotPassword(
    @Query("email") email:String,
    @Query("sig") sig:String,
    @Query("salt") salt:String
):Response<ForgotDataClass>
```

main activity

```
viewModel.forgotPassword(email,sig1,salt1)
                    viewModel.myPassword.observe(this, { response ->
                        if (response.isSuccessful){
                            when(response.body()?.status){
                                "1" -> {
                                    finish()
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "your password reset successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                                "-2" -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Email is not exit ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                                else -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Try again something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Try again something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
```

Comment: Clear your question. I cant understand what you means

Comment: when i click button i got old response and after some micro sec i got new response  i don't want old response

Comment: how can i get only new response

Comment: you may not use suspend becuase retrofit can provide enqueue method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. You can return your `LiveData` like this and I don't think you need a global variable. And use `postValue` when using a different thread to update you `MutableLiveData`

```
class ForgotPasswordViewModel(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

    fun forgotPassword(email: String, sig: String, salt: String): LiveData {
        var myPassword = MutableLiveData<Response<ForgotDataClass>>()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            myPassword.postValue(repository.forgotPassword(email, sig, salt))
        }
        return myPassword
    }
}
```

In your fragment/activity you can call like this

```
viewModel.forgotPassword(email,sig1,salt1).observe(this) { response ->
    // do stuff with your result
}
```

**Edit**

To handle errors you can wrap your call in a try-catch block like this and catch and operate on these errors.

```
    fun forgotPassword(email: String, sig: String, salt: String): LiveData {
        var myPassword = MutableLiveData<Response<ForgotDataClass>>()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                myPassword.postValue(repository.forgotPassword(email, sig, salt))
            } catch(e: HttpException) {
               // handle
            }
        }
        return myPassword
    }
}
```

Comment: how can handle when api is wrong or api did not give any response

Comment: @androiuseru what I do is wrap the actual call in a `try-catch` block and handle the error there. See edit.